# Android: Function similar to filteredArrayUsingPredicate in iOS

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a JSONArray object in android and I would like to add criteria to filter the array. However, i searched the web and it seems that people are using "for-loop" to filter out the JSONObject they want in the array.

Will there be a function similar to "filteredArrayUsingPredicate" in iOS, I am quite surprised to see there are no people talking on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the Predicate page on Apple's iOS site makes me think its closest analog is C# LINQ or Java 8 Lambda Expressions. As Android doesn't support Java 8 there are third party libraries like RetroLambda for Android which attempt to support such features.